# can "File system check exit code is 8" be repaired?

Tags: ssd, repair

I have a startup disk from my old computer with error File system check exit code is 8.

can this be repaired?  I would like to use it to migrate files and settings to my new computer, it is an SSD if that makes any dif.  I do have the filed from this disk backed up but not the system settings needed for migration assistant to move tho new mac.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking it depends on what you mean by repaired.

That error indicates that the filesystem on that disk is damaged. The good news is that if you reformat it the disk will still be usable. That is also bad news, as you may have noted.

You can try running disk utility on that drive a few times (3 - 4) and see if is repairable. Depending on the filesystem in use on the drive you may be able to use something like DiskWarrior to fix the disk. But beware that DiskWarrior and pretty much all disk repair utilities can't repair APFS volumes (yet).

If that is the case you can try a data *recovery* utility or sending the drive off to be recovered for you, which can be expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the info Steve.  What I meant by repair, is return it to pre screwed up condition as a startup disk.  The files on it were backed up, but the system folder with all of my settings was not.  I'll give disk warrior a shot, if that doesn't fly I guess it will get reformatted. The SSD isn't an APFS volume so I am keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: un-screwing a disk error is not always possible, but if anything can do it DW would be my choice.

Comment: DW did the trick, back to normal on all counts, short of a couple non essential files being damaged.  Couldn't be more thrilled.

Comment: Cool, DW is a great tool, hope they be working hard on APFS support!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that recent Linux distributions (such as Ubuntu) may be able to gain read-only access on an unencrypted HFS+ drive, even if macOS is showing Error 8.

Although this won't be a great way to migrate a system off it, it may be a fairly good way to recover individual documents and files.